# Table In IText not adding correct Cells

Tags: java, itext

I am creating a document in Itext and have it broken down into 4 main Cell which have tables nested within them. I am creating the last cell of my document and cannot get anything but the first cell in every row to show up.

Here is the function I'm calling which is returning a cell that I am adding to my main document.

```
public PdfPCell getPSBioCell() {

    PdfPCell spaceCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
    spaceCell.setColspan(1); // space
    spaceCell.setBorder(0);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
    PdfPCell main = new PdfPCell();
    noBorder(main);//
    main.setPadding(0);//


    PdfPCell dist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_rangerDistrict, nf));
     PdfPCell district = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(this.sale.getRangerDistrict(), nf));
    PdfPCell saleD = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_saleDate, nf));
    PdfPCell saleDate = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(this.formatDateString(sale.getSaleDate()), nf));
    PdfPCell awardD = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_awardDate, nf));
    PdfPCell awardDate = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(this.formatDateString(sale.getAwardDate()), nf));
    PdfPCell termD = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_termDate, nf));
    PdfPCell termDate = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(this.formatDateString(sale.getTerminationDate()), nf));
    PdfPCell avg = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_avgDbh , nf));
    PdfPCell avgDbh = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(this.formatNumberString(String.valueOf(sale.getAveDiam())), nf));
    PdfPCell cruis = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_cruiser, nf));
    PdfPCell cruiser = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(sale.getCruiser(), nf));
    noBorder(dist, district, saleD, saleDate);
    noBorder(awardD, awardDate, termD, termDate, avg);
    noBorder(avgDbh, cruis, cruiser);
    //
    table.addCell(dist);
    table.addCell(district);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    //
    table.addCell(saleD);
    table.addCell(saleDate);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    //
    table.addCell(awardD);
    table.addCell(awardDate);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    //
    table.addCell(termD);
    table.addCell(termDate);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    //
    table.addCell(avg);
    table.addCell(avgDbh);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    //
    table.addCell(cruis);
    table.addCell(cruiser);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);
    table.addCell(spaceCell);


    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    main.addElement(table);
    return main;
}
```

Comment: Change your code into a standalone example that can be downloaded and executed without any extra work, and someone may take a look. Now, you've just pasted some code that requires effort to test, and not many people have the time to puzzle it together into a standalone example. You may think such people are lazy, but take into account that those people may think the same thing about you for not providing a standalone example. After all: you are probably paid for your job. People on SO aren't paid for their answer.

Comment: I had a look at the code and have to say that @Bruno is right. There are so many unknown factors in the code (values of member variables and return values of method calls) that trying to reproduce the issue is virtually impossible without the added input from a crystal ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was In my `noBorder(PdfPcell)` function I was doing `cell.setBorder(0)` but i was also doing `cell.noWrap(true)` so setting the border to `0` and the noWrap to `true` I couldn't see the other cells being pushed off the completed Pdf page.